# There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400), missing parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, spring

Trying to RequestMapping a submit, but I get this error, and I really dont understand why, because I thought everyone was provided :

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required Integer parameter 'idVac' is not present
```

[...]

```
function deleteRecord(idVac) {

var newwindow;
newwindow=window.confirm("Are you sure");
if(newwindow == true) {
    alert("Condition is true");
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("name", "form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "/vacEditDelete");
    var vacancyId = document.createElement("input");
    vacancyId.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    vacancyId.setAttribute("name", "vacancyId");
    vacancyId.setAttribute("value", idVac);

    var csrf = document.createElement("input");
    csrf.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    csrf.setAttribute("name", "${_csrf.parameterName}");
    csrf.setAttribute("value", "${_csrf.token}");
    form.appendChild(csrf);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();

}
}
```

The method upon is mapping on this method in my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vacEditDelete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteVacancy(@AuthenticationPrincipal User currentuser,
                            @RequestParam(value = "idVac", required = true) Integer idVac){
    System.out.println("Method called");
    vacService.deleteVacancyByID(idVac);

    return "redirect:/vacEdit";


}
```

Comment: it is `vacancyId` not `idVac` at least that is the field you are manually creating in the form.

Comment: So if i change `value = "idVac"`to `value = "vacancyId"`, it would be correct ? So if I give a form a name then it is the value for a `RequestParam` annotiation ?

Comment: The name of the `@RequestParam` should be a give away. It expects a request parameter, you are specifying the wrong name and so it will never be seen by spring. The name of the form element (not the form!) is important here. So yes change it.

Comment: Ok changed it and now it says that `vacancyId` wouldn't be a present Integer, I don't get it to be honest.

Comment: Your form only contains the csfr the other fields aren't appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you are expecting @RequestParam(value = **"idVac"**, required = true)

While in JS you are sending vacancyId.setAttribute("name", **"vacancyId"**);

refer [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)

Element Detail

```
value

public abstract String value

The name of the request parameter to bind to.

Default:
```

Comment: Yea but this is just the name, thought I just need the value

Comment: js form field name and java controller request parameter names should be same

Comment: Well thats awkward, it says now that `vacancyId` wouldnt be a present Integer parameter, although the name is `vacancyId`

Comment: Can you share exact error you are getting after updating parameter name

Comment: Yea of course : `There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required Integer parameter 'vacancyId' is not present`

Comment: you are not doing form.appendChild(vacancyId); in your js code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78704/discussion-between-datprettyurkel-and-amit-rk3).

Comment: Chat link is blocked from office network :) .. Did u try adding append code in js